# Order of top competencies percentages on SO careers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to be able to reorder the `top 10/20/30 %` in the my Stack Overflow Careers Profile.

I would like to highlight some of them but some competencies like `string` appears before other more important, because I have this one first than other. I know we can hide them, but, I just would like to highlight the most 5 important of each level (`10/20/30 %`).

Is there any way to implement a basic order management of this competencies?

Thank you.